# How to find, and standardize the spelling of chapter and page references (Adobe InDesign)?

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I want to find digits followed by "f", "ff", "f." or "ff." to standardize the spelling following given conventions/rules.

I already tried some regular expressions, but unfortunately I did not find an universal expression grabbing all of the cases above (f, ff, f., ff.).

In spoken words it seems easy:

- find digits
- followed by an optional whitespace
- then followed by f, ff, f. or ff.
- only whitespaces or NOT word boundaries are allowed before and after the expression

The beginning of the regex is quite easy, but I can’t figure out how to handle the different "f"-cases and the NOT boundaries following.

---

My best guess yet is:

```
(?<=\b)(\d+(\h|\b)?f{1,2})\.?
```

but then still the stings followed by a word character are found.

---

When I extend the regex to:

```
(?<=\b)(\d+(\h|\b)?f{1,2})\.?(\W)
```

the numbered of "false funds" are decreasing, but still it is not the solution

---

I prepared lines for testing.
The lines containing a plus "+" should be found, at the same time the ones with a minus "-" should not be found.

```
00f aaa +
00f. aaa +
00ff aaa +
00ff. aaa +
00 f aaa + 
00 f. aaa +
00 ff aaa +
00 ff. aaa +
+ aaa 00f aaa +
+ aaa 00f. aaa +
+ aaa 00ff aaa +
+ aaa 00ff. aaa +
+ aaa 00 f aaa + 
+ aaa 00 f. aaa +
+ aaa 00 ff aaa +
+ aaa 00 ff. aaa +
+ aaa 00f
+ aaa 00f.
+ aaa 00ff
+ aaa 00ff.
+ aaa 00 f 
+ aaa 00 f.
+ aaa 00 ff
+ aaa 00 ff.

00 faaa -
00 f.aaa -
00 ffaaa -
00 ff.aaa -
00af aaa - 
00af. aaa -
00aff aaa -
00aff. aaa -
- aaa 00 faaa -
- aaa 00 f.aaa -
- aaa 00 ffaaa -
- aaa 00 ff.aaa -
- aaa 00af aaa - 
- aaa 00af. aaa -
- aaa 00aff aaa -
- aaa 00aff. aaa -
- aaa00f
- aaa00f.
- aaa00ff
- aaa00ff.
- aaa 00af 
- aaa 00af.
- aaa 00aff
- aaa 00aff.

00faaa -
00f.aaa -
00ffaaa -
00ff.aaa -
00af aaa - 
00af. aaa -
00aff aaa -
00aff. aaa -
- aaa00 faaa -
- aaa00 f.aaa -
- aaa00 ffaaa -
- aaa00 ff.aaa -
- aaa00af aaa - 
- aaa00af. aaa -
- aaa00aff aaa -
- aaa00aff. aaa -
- aaa00af 
- aaa00af.
- aaa00aff
- aaa00aff.
```

Further, the aim is to group the digits anf "f"-cases in a manner, so that they can be uses in a replacement-expression to standardize the spelling to one of those cases:

- 123 ff. (with whitespace, with dot)
- 123 ff (with whitespace, without dot)
- 123ff. (without whitespace, with dot)
- 123ff (without whitespace, without dot)

Comment: would be helpful if you add language you are working with to your tags

Answer (score 6):

I suggest

```
\b(\d+)(\s?)(f{1,2})(?:(\.)\B|\b(?!\.))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4T8EZI/5)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: 1+ digits
- `(\s?)` - Group 2: an optional whitespace
- `(f{1,2})` - Group 3: 1 or 2 `f`s
- `(?:(\.)\B|\b(?!\.))` - either of the two:

  - `(\.)\B` - a `.` captured in Group 4 if not followed with a word char
  - `|` - or
  - `\b(?!\.)` - a word boundary not followed with a dot.

Then, replacing is easy with:

- `123 ff.`: `$1 $3.`
- `123 ff` : `$1 $3`
- `123ff.` : `$1$3.`
- `123ff`  : `$1$3`

If the whitespace and dot are not necessary in replacement patterns, remove the groupings and adjust the IDs in the replacement backreferences.

Comment: Hi, whilst looking at my own solution and checking yours, e.g. 00 f.!aaa aaa +
would still match, but this doesn't adhere to requirements, since only whitespace/boundry at the end is allowed...?

Comment: @vs97 No idea why you think so. `ff.` is followed with a non-word boundary and it *does* meet the requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Interestingly, running [your regexp](https://regex101.com/r/4T8EZI/3) via Adobe InDesign's _Find/Change_ feature yields the exact same matches as [your regexp with the flavor set to ECMAScript](https://regex101.com/r/4T8EZI/4), i.e. several wanted matches are not found.

Comment: @RobC I wrote: *`(\h?)` - Group 2: an optional horizontal whitespace **(use `\s` if any whitespace is allowed here)**. [My `\b(\d+)(\s?)(f{1,2})(?:(\.)\B|\b(?!\.))` regex works](https://regex101.com/r/4T8EZI/5). Edited to get rid of `\h`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yes using `\s` instead does rectify the issue.

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this?

```
\b\d+\s?(?:ff|f)+\.?(?=\s)
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9LX7/6)

```
\b          start with word boundary
\d+         match all digits
\s?         match optional whitespace
(?:ff|f)+   non-capturing group, match either ff or f
\.?         match optional dot (basically checking for ff. or ff or f. or f)
(?=\s)      match if followed by whitespace, without making the whitespace part of the match
```

With groups, same expression looks like:

```
\b(\d+)\s?((?:ff|f)+\.?)(?=\s)
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9LX7/7)

Replacement can be achieved via different combinations of the `$1` and `$2` groups.